# How can I isolate a bug in php?

Tags: php, debugging

How can I print out an error to the console by isolating it? I have been reading about the `print_r();` and `die('');` functions, but I don't understand how to use them. Can anyone give me a rundown with an example?

for example if I had this passing through the array would I use `print_r($my_db_connect);` ?

```
public static function get_store_info(){ 
       global $my_db_connect
       $sql = "SELECT animalname, animaltype, caretaker FROM store"
       return $my_db_connect ->the_array($sql, true);
}
```

where would I use the `print_r();` and pass the array to return and then should I use `die();`right after?

I know about this one but it doesn't isolate it just shows all the errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Instead of echoing values to the normal output of your strip it usually is much more efficient to write a log file in background. There you can examine custom output without it getting mixed with the normal script output in unpredictable ways.

Comment: `print_r` is just a way of outputting a variable in a useful manner so you can see what it contains. `die` then stops things from continuing after that point. You'd do `print_r($my_db_connect)` if you weren't sure what `$my_db_connect` contained. You'd do `print_r($my_db_connect ->the_array($sql, true))` to see what that call returns. You might do `print_r($sql)` to make sure your SQL query is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the script

Comment: If using `mysqli` also add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: thank you! Just got it right before I rechecked this

Comment: by the way if you only want to log the error in your log file you can use this command:
error_log("Some error here....", 0);